# Is CUDPP 2.0 debugging properly for a Nsight debug instance in CUDA 4.2, Nsight 2.2?

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-debugging

I have upgraded a project from CUDA 4.0, Nsight 2.0 to CUDA 4.2, Nsight 2.2, recompiling CUDPP on CUDA 4.2. I can use breakpoints and step device code properly after the upgrade, but when my code calls a cudppScan() function Nsight reports acess violations even if the function is doing the operation properly and returning the correct prefix-sum of the values. Release or Debug code being running without Nsight doesn't present problems. The issue can be reproduced by the following snippet.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cudpp/cudpp.h>

//Cudpp testing
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#define ARRAY_SIZE 32

unsigned int uiArraySize = sizeof(unsigned int)*ARRAY_SIZE;
unsigned int h_auiTest[ARRAY_SIZE];
for(int i = 0 ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; ++i)
{
    h_auiTest[i] = 1;
}

unsigned int *d_auiTest;
GPUMALLOC((void**)&d_auiTest , uiArraySize);
TOGPU(d_auiTest , h_auiTest , uiArraySize);

unsigned int *d_auiOut;
GPUMALLOC((void**)&d_auiOut , uiArraySize);

CUDPPHandle cudppContext;
CUDPPHandle scanPlan;

CUDPP_SAFE_CALL(cudppCreate(&cudppContext));
CUDPPConfiguration scanConfig;
scanConfig.algorithm = CUDPP_SCAN;
scanConfig.datatype  = CUDPP_UINT;
scanConfig.op        = CUDPP_ADD;
scanConfig.options   = CUDPP_OPTION_EXCLUSIVE | CUDPP_OPTION_FORWARD;

cudppPlan(cudppContext , &scanPlan, scanConfig, ARRAY_SIZE , 1, 0);

cudppScan(scanPlan, d_auiOut, d_auiTest , ARRAY_SIZE);

FROMGPU(h_auiTest , d_auiOut , uiArraySize);

for(int i = 0 ; i < ARRAY_SIZE ; ++i)
{
    assert(h_auiTest[i] == i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I got for this issue is downgrading my project to CUDA 4.0.